Does anyone know what processor AWS Aurora Serverless v2 uses?
Does anyone know what processor AWS Aurora Serverless v2 uses?
Also is is possible to specify which processor to use in AWS Aurora Serverless v2?

No and no, that is point of the offering: you do not need to and should not worry about the hardware. Specify the number of ACUs and be done with it. Same with Fargate and Lambda.
